# Rotação de z para 90 graus ao cair no chão Projeto em 2D

Tags: unity-5

Sou bem leigo no assunto ainda, mas estou aprendendo a programar. Para deixar meu jogo de plataforma mais legal eu habilitei a rotação do personagem, mas quero fazer um jeito que ao cair e encostar no chão ele já volte para 90 graus de novo, só que tenho dificuldades para fazer isso
Nota: Eu já fiz um jeito que ele identifique que está encostando no chão

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
    {
        IsJumping = false;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
    {
        IsJumping = true;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando o GameObject do personagem encostar no chão, use:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 90);
```